# Naming and Calling jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
            $('#seconds').spinner({
                spin: function(event, ui) {
                    if (ui.value >= 60) {
                        $(this).spinner('value', ui.value - 60);
                        $('#minutes').spinner('stepUp');
                        return false;
                    } else if (ui.value < 0) {
                        $(this).spinner('value', ui.value + 60);
                        $('#minutes').spinner('stepDown');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can I name a function that includes same code above and how can I call it?

Comment: `function whatever() { /*your code */ }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this should work:

```
$('#seconds').spinner({
  spin: doSpin
});

function doSpin(event, ui) {
  if (ui.value >= 60) {
    $(this).spinner('value', ui.value - 60);
    $('#minutes').spinner('stepUp');
    return false;
  } else if (ui.value < 0) {
    $(this).spinner('value', ui.value + 60);
    $('#minutes').spinner('stepDown');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to extend jQuery/create a jQuery plugin, you could use:

```
$.fn.mySpinner = function() {
    this.spinner({
        spin: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.value >= 60) {
                $(this).spinner('value', ui.value - 60);
                $('#minutes').spinner('stepUp');
                return false;
            } else if (ui.value < 0) {
                $(this).spinner('value', ui.value + 60);
                $('#minutes').spinner('stepDown');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
};

$('#seconds').mySpinner();
```

(Although it looks like dave's answer may be closer to the mark.)